# mysql taking one row from a table and minus multiple rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have some trouble trying to figure out how to do the following task.

Table 1

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Apple      ║ Banana      ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 20         ║ 15          ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

table 2

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Cat        ║ Banana      ║Apple        ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ bbb        ║ 10          ║ 1           ║
║ 2 ║ aaa        ║ 2           ║ 2           ║
║ 3 ║ abc        ║ 1           ║ 3           ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

so there are banana and apple in both table, 
i would like to take a row from table 1 (which is going to be Apple = 20, and banana = 15) and use these numbers to minus all the rows in table 2's column banana and apple while both table have different ways to order the columns.

i would like to get a result of

```
apple = 14 ( which is done by doing 20 - 1 - 2 - 3)
banana = 2 (which is done by doing 15 - 10 - 2 - 1)
```

is there any ways to do this in a query instead of saving the values from somewhere and doing the math one by one?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
select t2.Apple - t1.a
     , t2.Banana - t1.b
from (select sum(banana) as b, sum(apple) as a from tbl2) t1
join tbl1 t2
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i am gonna give it a try first.

Comment: just wondering when i do something like t2.Apple - t1.Apple.. 
if both of them have type of string, is it still gonna work from mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do it by one SQL - but if there will be more data in tables, this will be extremely slow.
Better is make 2 separate queries and do math in PHP.

Comment: there is actually about 15 columns that i need to calculate, and there are so far 50 rows of it, it will grow time to time tho, how would it be done if i seperate it into 2 queries?

Comment: in 50 rows, that should work - but if you will have like 500-1000 rows, this can work quite slow. It depend on many other conditions. 
From my experience - such select in select work like 2-3s, and in 2 rows + php it was like 0,2s - with same amount of data & same results, no other changes in table structure.

Comment: i guess i will just stick to 1 query for now and see how bad it gets before i make adjustments.